# check if JList has a specific value

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jlist

I want to know if it is possible to check a JList (or the JList model) for a specific value using a if statement.

I want to use `list.setSelectedValue()` to highlight the current value, but if the value is not in the JList it throws an error, therefore I want to use an if to check if it is in the JList.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JList#getNextMatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getNextMatch%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.Position.Bias%29) method the following:

```
String s = "element";//Say you want to look up for String "element "
int index = list.getNextMatch(s,0,Position.Bias.Forward);
if (index != -1)
list.setSelectedValue(s,true);
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using a [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) in your JList you can use the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method like this:

```
DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel;
model.contains(theObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static boolean hasElement(Object searched, JList list) {
      for (int a = 0; a < list.getModel().getSize(); a++) {
         Object element = list.getModel().getElementAt(a);
         if (element.equals(searched))  {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
```